# How to create a single sign-on system for a number of external services

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I have a site where a user can register. After the registration is finished, he can connect some accounts: facebook, googlemail, vkontakte.ru, etc.

I want to store username and password of these site and when the user logs in the next time to my site, the user should be logged in to those services without typing the username and password in them separately. He should just log into my site and then have access to the other sites.

How can I write PHP code for this process?

Comment: I'm not particularly knowledgeable on this topic, but you might have some luck looking for OAuth solutions for these services.

Answer (score 0):

You can't authenticate users to other sites with server side code.
Even with a client side script (ie. submitting the login form to other websites from yours) you can't. They won't allow you to do so because of `CSRF` protection.